# vim fo=aq and crontab footgun: Why are my crontab commands treated as comments?

Tags: syntax

After a large amount of trial-and-error narrowing, the problem is a conflict between the default crontab syntax file and `formatoptions` flags containing anything that includes `aq`, i.e. both `a` (autoformat) and `q` (format comments). It seems like `q` causes the comment leader to be placed when autowrapping comment lines.

I use `caq` set, and others, so that my comment blocks get formatted by vim while code remains ignored. Although there are times when this configuration causes frustration, this most recent incarnation of it has me scratching my head more vigorously than usual!

I looked at the syntax in question and it seems reasonable to me, but I don't really know how to read a syntax script.

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: crontab
" Maintainer: David Necas (Yeti) <yeti@physics.muni.cz>
" Original Maintainer: John Hoelzel johnh51@users.sourceforge.net
" License: This file can be redistribued and/or modified under the same terms
"   as Vim itself.
" Filenames: /tmp/crontab.* used by "crontab -e"
" Last Change: 2015-01-20
"
" crontab line format:
" Minutes   Hours   Days   Months   Days_of_Week   Commands # comments

" quit when a syntax file was already loaded
if exists("b:current_syntax")
        finish
endif

syntax match crontabNick "^\s*@\(reboot\|yearly\|annually\|monthly\|weekly\|daily\|midnight\|hourly\)\>" nextgroup=crontabCmd skipwhite

syntax match crontabVar "^\s*\k\w*\s*="me=e-1

syntax case ignore

syntax match crontabMin "^\s*[-0-9/,.*]\+" nextgroup=crontabHr skipwhite
syntax match crontabHr "\s[-0-9/,.*]\+" nextgroup=crontabDay skipwhite contained
syntax match crontabDay "\s[-0-9/,.*]\+" nextgroup=crontabMnth skipwhite contained

syntax match crontabMnth "\s[-a-z0-9/,.*]\+" nextgroup=crontabDow skipwhite contained
syntax keyword crontabMnth12 contained jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec

syntax match crontabDow "\s[-a-z0-9/,.*]\+" nextgroup=crontabCmd skipwhite contained
syntax keyword crontabDow7 contained sun mon tue wed thu fri sat

syntax region crontabCmd start="\S" end="$" skipwhite contained keepend contains=crontabPercent
syntax match crontabCmnt "^\s*#.*" contains=@Spell
syntax match crontabPercent "[^\\]%.*"lc=1 contained

" Define the default highlighting.
" Only when an item doesn't have highlighting yet

hi def link crontabMin          Number
hi def link crontabHr           PreProc
hi def link crontabDay          Type

hi def link crontabMnth         Number
hi def link crontabMnth12               Number
hi def link crontabMnthS                Number
hi def link crontabMnthN                Number

hi def link crontabDow          PreProc
hi def link crontabDow7         PreProc
hi def link crontabDowS         PreProc
hi def link crontabDowN         PreProc

hi def link crontabNick         Special
hi def link crontabVar          Identifier
hi def link crontabPercent              Special

" comment out next line for to suppress unix commands coloring.
hi def link crontabCmd          Statement

hi def link crontabCmnt         Comment


let b:current_syntax = "crontab"

" vim: ts=8
```

It would seem a complete bug to me to have the command line treated as a comment.

Video demonstration of minimal reproduction... https://youtu.be/9RDbnwFn4Rw

Anyway, the effective mitigation for this is

```
au filetype crontab set formatoptions=
```

And even though I will never care that I won't be able to ever have vim autowrapping comments for me in the crontab, hopefully someone can come along who understands vim syntax files and explain what bug to blame for the awful default behavior.